# .htaccess redirect to mobile version issues

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I have tried to solve this problem looking about the internet before asking but cannot solve it this is as far as I have got.

Basically I have two websites on one hosting account. Both websites have their own domain such as:
www.website1.com
www.website2.com

Website 1 goes to the root folder to get the website information (index.htm etc)

Website 2 is in a sub directory 
/website2/

Website 1 already has a mobile version avalabile at:
www.mobile.website1.com

Website 2 is a new website and I have yet to develop a mobile version of the site. But the problem is the ht access thats in the root folder is redirecting anything to the mobile version of the first site if your on a mobile device.

So for example if I wish to go onto website 2 on my phone it will take me to the mobile version of website 1.

can anyone see my issue and help? like i said i have tried to find a solution elsewhere but had no luck and checked all previous questions.

```
##BEGIN MOBILE (do not edit below this line)
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ((.*iPhone.*)|(.*iPod.*)|(.*BlackBerry.*)|(.*Android.*Mobile.*)|(.*Windows\ CE.*)|(.*IEMobile.*)|(.*Opera\ Mini.*)|(.*Opera\ Mobi.*))
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !dm_show_classic
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !no_redirect=true [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.website1.com/ [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website2.com [L]
RewriteBase /
##END MOBILE
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website1\.com [NC]` this condition should prevent the redirect, since you are going to website2 and not website1. Maybe something else is going on

Comment: I have the same thought I have put so much research into this before asking and still nothing works Oh well ill ring go daddy in the morning see if they can resolve the problem. Cheers for trying guys.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and work for me:

```
##BEGIN MOBILE (do not edit below this line)
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ((.*iPhone.*)|(.*iPod.*)|(.*BlackBerry.*)|(.*Android.*Mobile.*)|(.*Windows\ CE.*)|(.*IEMobile.*)|(.*Opera\ Mini.*)|(.*Opera\ Mobi.*))
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !dm_show_classic
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !no_redirect=true [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.website1.com/ [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ((.*iPhone.*)|(.*iPod.*)|(.*BlackBerry.*)|(.*Android.*Mobile.*)|(.*Windows\ CE.*)|(.*IEMobile.*)|(.*Opera\ Mini.*)|(.*Opera\ Mobi.*))
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !dm_show_classic
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !no_redirect=true [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website2.com [L]
RewriteBase /
##END MOBILE
```

Comment: tried this and still cannot get it to work I think there maybe a problem with the server itself, Thanks for attempting.

Comment: aaron, could you copy the full .htaccess file?
It could be a problem with the redirection  from www.site2.com site1.com/site2/